# Aren't $ f’(xy) $ and $ f’(x/y)$ ambiguous notations?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions

Sources: [*Calculus: Early Transcendentals* (6 edn 2007)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0495011665). p. 890, Section 14.3. Exercise 50b, c..

> [image]

Defining $t = xy$ transforms $f(xy)$ into $f(t)$, but this doesn't change the truth that $f$ depends on 2 independent variables ($x, y$) and so is multivariable.

1. So how is writing $f'$ correct? $f$ isn't single-variable.
2. Can the following be simplified more?

(b) $\partial_y z = x \dfrac{ df(\color{darkorchid}{xy}) }{ d(\color{darkorchid}{xy}) } $
(c) $\partial_x z =  \dfrac{ df(\color{green}{x/y}) }{ d(\color{green}{x/y}) } \dfrac{1}{y} $?

Comment: "The function f here depends on two variables" No, f is a function of a single variable. Ad there is no ambiguity in the notation.

Answer (score 5):

The function $f$ depends on only one variable - there's no comma between the parentheses. So for the given function $t\mapsto f(t)$, there is a single derivative $t\mapsto f'(t)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(t+h)-f(t)}{h}$. Then $f'(xy)$ is just obtained by pugging $t=xy$ into $f'(t)$. This should not be mixed with the partial derivatives of the function in two variables $(x,y)\mapsto f(xy)$.
For example, if $f(t)=t^3$ then $f'(t)=3t^2$, so 
$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} =yf'(xy)=3y^3x^2$ etc.

Comment: "there's no comma between the parentheses." I agree, but how does this make $f$ one-variable? $f$ obviously depends on two independent variables: $x,y$.

Answer (score 0):

Here $f$ is a function of a single variable and $f'$ refers to the ordinary derivative.

Comment: Would you please enlarge on your answer therein (and not as a comment)? I don't apprehend how it answers my questions.

Comment: How is $f$ a function of a single variable? $f$ obviously depends on two independent variables: $x,y$.

Comment: This still puzzles you after four years? And no, $f$ does not obviously or even nonobviously depend on two independent variables. $z$ does.