# Why aren't $z_1 = f(xy)$ and $z_2 = f(x/y)$ multivariable?

Tags: functions

Sources: [*Calculus: Early Transcendentals* (6 edn 2007)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0495011665). p. 890, Section 14.3. Exercise 50b, c.

[This user](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/738461/53259) wrote that $z_1 = f(xy)$ and $z_2 = f(x/y)$  depend

> on only one variable - there's no comma between the parentheses.

Defining $t_1 = xy$ transforms $f(xy)$ into $f(t_1)$, and $t_2 = x/y$ transforms $f(x/y)$ into $f(t_2)$. Yes, $f(t_1)$ and $f(t_2)$ are single-variable.

But doesn't this misrepresent the original 2 independent variables ($x, y$)? 
These definitions don't change the original truth that $f$ did depend on 2 independent variables. So $f$ is multivariable.

Comment: The point *is* to ignore the $x$ and $y$ since you're using the chain rule.  $t$ is a multivariate function of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Perhaps an example would help, the function $f(xy)=e^{xy}\sin(xy)+(xy)^3$ may look like a multivariable function in $x$ and $y$, but it can be written more simply as a univariate function, $f(t)=e^t\sin t+t^3$.

Answer (score 1):

The function $f: X \mapsto f(X)$ is not multivariable. The function $m: (X,Y) \mapsto XY $ ("multiplication", if you like) is multivariable. The function $g:(X,Y) \mapsto Z_1$ is multivariable, and given by $g = f \circ m$, so $$g(x,y)=f(m(x,y))=f(xy). $$